# Grouping lists in list-of-lists using tolerance and even if lists are shifted

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm trying to compare shapes of rectangular (or similar) panels.
I'm breaking these polylines into lists of tuples with a line vector and curve lengths.
Now I need to compare each list to all other lists (which are not all the same length, some shapes might have 3 edges, 4 or more) with a tolerance on the lengths.

For example this list of lists, and a tolerance of 0.1:

```
[[(vector1, 1.1), (vector2, 2.2), (vector3, 1.3), (vector4, 2.4)],
[(vector2, 2.3), (vector3, 1.4), (vector4, 2.5), (vector1, 1.2)],
[(vector1, 1.3), (vector2, 2.4), (vector3, 1.5), (vector4, 2.6)],
[(vector1, 5.1), (vector2, 6.4), (vector3, 5.5)]]
```

In this case the first two lists should group (i.e put into a new list), even though vector1 has shifted to the end of the second list, it is still a sequence that is in the same order and fits the tolerance of 0.1. The third and fourth lists should not be grouped at all (i.e lists with a single item) as they are not within the tolerance of any other list.

**IMPORTANT**: each entire list of tuples is an item. I'm comparing entire lists to entire lists, and at the end I'm grouping the item 'i's. In this example it'll be: [[0,1],[2],[3]]

I have come across list comprehensions with zip but these require all lists to be of equal length, and also things like intersect:

```
c = sorted(set(a).intersection(b))
```

But these use sets, while in my case item number within a list is important as well as the order of items, even if shifted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should `[("vector1", 1.1)] [("vector1", 1.2)] [("vector1", 1.3)]` be grouped together if tolerance is `0.1`?

Comment: No, I'll add it to the post: the entire list of tuples is an item. I'm comparing entire lists to entire lists, and at the end I'm grouping the item 'i's. In this example it'll be: [[0,1],[2],[3]]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it basically by brute forcing the problem. I understand this would be very heavy in a huge list, but for me it worked brilliantly. First I made sure all curves (lengths) are sorted in the same direction, then I rotated the list in a for loop `for range(0, len(list))`, and then I compared each iteration of each list to the original list.

If one of the rotated lists matched (math.isclose) the original list (each length was in the tolerance given) I removed that list and the matching lists from the original list of lists, and then the loop runs again with the updated list.